# DataGridView geting row index in c# gets exception out of range

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview, outofrangeexception

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e){

menoDB = dataGridView1.Rows[idSelectedRow].Cells["meno"].Value.ToString();      
priezviskoDB = dataGridView1.Rows[idSelectedRow].Cells["priezvisko"].Value.ToString();       
kontaktDB = dataGridView1.Rows[idSelectedRow].Cells["kontakt"].Value.ToString();      
zaplatenetDB = dataGridView1.Rows[idSelectedRow].Cells["platene"].Value.ToString();
}

idSelectedRow = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["idludia"].Value.ToString());
```

It works perfectly in first 2 rows, but when I click on 3th it reads from 10th (the last one) after that when I click on 4th I get this exception.

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled

It is obvious it try to read from 11th row but there is no 11th row.

Comment: Based on your last line, looks like you already solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue at this line:

```
idSelectedRow = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["idludia"].Value.ToString());
```

Now in your `idSelectedRow` you don't have the row index but `idludia` value. So change your code in this way:

```
menoDB = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["meno"].Value.ToString();      
priezviskoDB = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["priezvisko"].Value.ToString();       
kontaktDB = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["kontakt"].Value.ToString();      
zaplatenetDB = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["platene"].Value.ToString();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It solved my problem.
Now actually I don't even need idSelectedRow, because I dont use it anywhere else.